# 5 input based search form for Android

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, android, sqlite

I've been trying to look for a better way in which a user has up to 5 inputs in which they can search for results in a database.

I have 2 `EditText`s in which the user can have alphanumeric values and 3 `Spinner`s. As you can see in the code, it's badly designed in the way it consists of `if` or `else if` statements which is just horrible, but it works.

What would be the best way to avoid long `if` or `else if` statements and be able to pick and choose what you would like to search for in the database? I know there is the `switch` but does that not just take a value and return the result of something on the one `case`?

```
if(tag != "" && name != "" && breed != "Breed" && sex != "Sex"){
    cursor = cupboard().withDatabase(sqLiteDatabase).query(Cattle.class)
            .withSelection("tag LIKE ? AND name LIKE ? AND breed LIKE ? AND sex LIKE ?", tag, name, breed, sex)
            .getCursor();

    if(cursor.getCount() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry, No Cattle with those details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} else if (tag == "" && name == "" && breed == "Breed"){
    cursor = cupboard().withDatabase(sqLiteDatabase).query(Cattle.class)
            .withSelection("sex LIKE ?", sex)
            .getCursor();
    if(cursor.getCount() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry, No Cattle with those details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} else if (breed != "Breed"){
    cursor = cupboard().withDatabase(sqLiteDatabase).query(Cattle.class)
            .withSelection("breed LIKE ?", breed)
            .getCursor();
    if(cursor.getCount() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry, No Cattle with those details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} else if (sex != "Sex"){
    cursor = cupboard().withDatabase(sqLiteDatabase).query(Cattle.class)
            .withSelection("sex LIKE ?", sex)
            .getCursor();
    if(cursor.getCount() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry, No Cattle with those details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} else if (tag == "" && name == "" && sex == "Sex"){
    cursor = cupboard().withDatabase(sqLiteDatabase).query(Cattle.class)
            .withSelection("breed LIKE ?", breed)
            .getCursor();
    if(cursor.getCount() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry, No Cattle with those details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm a C# developer and I haven't written Java in ages.*

First of all I'd move this to a separate method, with `(String selection, String[] selectionArgs)` as parameters:

```
cursor = cupboard().withDatabase(sqLiteDatabase).query(Cattle.class)
        .withSelection(selection, selectionArgs)
        .getCursor();

if(cursor.getCount() < 1){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry, No Cattle with those details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can now call that method in each `if` instead of copy-pasting the same code over and over again and only changing a small part.

---

But I'm mostly baffled by the convoluted logic WRT those `if`s and the resulting `selection` and `selectionArgs`. Are you sure you didn't mean to construct something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var selectionOptions = new Dictionary<String, String>();

if(breed != "" && breed != "Breed")
{
   selectionOptions.Add("breed LIKE ?", breed);
}

if(sex != "" && sex != "Sex")
{
   selectionOptions.Add("sex LIKE ?", sex);
}

// same for tag and name 

// now construct the selection
var selection = string.Join(" AND ", selectionOptions.Keys);

// pass the selection and its arguments to the method I mentioned above
ThatMethodMentionedAbove(selection, selectionOptions.Values);
```

The logic being:

- Look at each of the four possible parameters
- Only add a parameter to the query if it has a value and its value is not its own name

That would make sense to me, whereas this kind of logic:

```
if (tag == "" && name == "" && breed == "Breed"){
    // snip
    .withSelection("sex LIKE ?", sex)
```

... just looks... odd. And indeed, very un-maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Even looking at your code has thought me something. Yeah it's complicated the way I wrote it alright and I fell into just coping and pasting the next statement to force it to work almost. The last code example you posted for the `tag`, `name`, `breed` should have been commented. Breed is a `Spinner` which the default value is `Breed`. I thought the logic of having the `Spinner` equal to `Breed` would show they are all default except the `sex` value.

Comment: small note: what you're advertising as Dictionary is named Map in java. of course you also know there's no var and that string.Join is not there in Java. Additional note: Maps don't guarantee traversal order as you want it here. Most maps do it right, but it's not guaranteed :/ (not that Dictionary would guarantee it either)

Comment: @Vogel612 Yeah, I know it isn't robust code, it's more about the idea, the logic: compile a list of key-value pairs and loop through that list to construct the query.

Comment: Yeah even the logic sounds better then the way I tried to do it xD. It's after clicking in my head on how you came across it in C# and how to implement it in my code! I actually really appreciate the help everyone as this is my first job which the app is demoing to a client and I was asked to do it and I don't want to write lazy code :)

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks for helping me out. Thanks to your code I was able to make it much cleaner, scalable and I've actually made the search way better thanks to you.

Comment: @SmiffyKmc You're welcome; I've been where you've been and have written code like yours too. Nice to know that I made the right call to respond to your question. ;-)